# Using CountableValueRange in rules

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm currently building a scheduling application for tasks sharing some resources.
Each task may use a certain percent of the resource.

What I need to check in Drools rules is that each shared resource is not used more than 100% by parallel tasks.

So code looks like :

```java
@Data
public class Resource {
   @PlanningId
   private Integer id;

   private String label;
}
```

```java
public class ResourceUsage {
   @PlanningId
   private Integer id;

   private Resource resource;

   private int usagePercent;

}
```

The entity to schedule

```java
@Data
@PlanningEntity
public class TaskAssignment {
   @PlanningId
   private Integer id;

   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "slotRange" })
   private Integer timeSlot;

   private int duration;
   private ResourceUsage resourceUsage;

   public Integer getEndingSlot() {
        return timeSlot + duration;
   }
}
```

And finally the solution

```java
@Data
@PlanningSolution
public class PlanningSolution {
  @PlanningId
  private Integer id;

  @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
  private List<TaskAssignment> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "slotRange")
  public CountableValueRange<Integer> getSlotRange() {
        return ValueRangeFactory.createIntValueRange(0, 10_000);
  }

  @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
  private Set<Resource> resources = new TreeSet<>();
}
```

Setters and getters are absent as I use Lombok to avoid writing them.

In the past, I was using a class for time slots and writing a rule to iterate over the collection of time slots was easy and I was able to check the global usage of each resource by time slot and penalize when usage was greater than 100%.

As I had problems with memory usage, I decided to turn the TimeSlot class into a *CountableValueRange* but now, I don't know how to create a rule matching each value of the range. to perform the same calculation as before.

Is there a way or do I have to switch back to my TimeSlot class ?

EDIT :
Could a shadow variable contained in a kind of shadow planning entity do the trick ?

Comment: Using CountableValueRange currently almost always implies using customer moves and often a custom construction heuristic to scale out. See the investment portfolio example. In future versions we're going to supply such custom moves and custom construction heuristics out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment, I managed to avoid using custom moves and will try to go on like this as the results are quite good. I'm only stuck with certain rules but as these are hard ones, I think I will code them on the Java side or provide complex methods usable in rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to write a rule which allows me to avoid iterating over time slots.
The idea is to count the usage at the beginning of an assignment

```
rule "Maximum usage of a resource"
       when
             $r : Resource()
             $p : TaskAssignment($id1 : id, $ts : timeSlot != null,
                                 resourceUsage!.ressource==$r,
                                 $usage : resourceUsage!.usagePercent);
             accumulate(TaskAssignment(timeSlot != null, timeSlot <= $ts, 
                                      endingSlot > $ts, id != $id1, 
                                      resourceUsage!.ressource==$r, 
                                      $rate : resourceUsage!.usagePercent);
                                  $s:sum($rate);
                                  $s + $usage > 100) 
       then
             scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 100-($s + $usage));         
end
```